# How does the MenuBar object at the bottom of Form work?

Tags: codenameone

I'm struggling with the MenuBar at the bottom of a form - the one indicated by the codenameone Javadocs here:

[image]

I can't seem to find an example, but from what I can tell, something like the following should work:

```
    public void start() {
        if(current != null){
            current.show();
            return;
        }

        Form hi = new Form("Welcome");
        MenuBar menubar = hi.getMenuBar();
        Command test = Command.create("TEST",null,(e)->{
            Log.p("test clicked");
        });
        menubar.addCommand(test);

        hi.show();
    }
```

However, I don't get a MenuBar.

Obviously I'm missing something basic here - can anyone show me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The menu bar logic is a bit old, you don't need to define that or use it. Modern Codename One applications use the `Toolbar` to place elements and usually add their content to the top of the `Form`. I'll update the JavaDoc to reflect that.

If you are interested in having a menu at the bottom of the form just do this:

```
Form myForm = new Form("With Menu at Bottom", new BorderLayout());
Container content = new Container(...);
myForm.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, content);
myForm.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, 
    GridLayout.encloseIn(4, menuButton1, menuButton2, menuButton3, menuButton4);
```

Just add your real content to `content` and create the buttons any way you like.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't assign a MenuBar to the form yet. First, you must create one and then assign it using the function

```
setMenuBar(MenuBar menubar)
```